# Configuring structuremap to create an instance using a factory class

Tags: structuremap

I want to configure structuremap to create a service using a factory class.  The factory itself has a dependency that needs filling.  Currently I have the following in my Registry class:

```
For<IDoStuffWebService>().Singleton().Use(() => 
    new DoStuffWebServiceClientFactory(new ConfigProvider()).Create()
);
```

Rather than having to hard-code the concrete type DoStuffWebServiceClientFactory and manually fill it's dependency, I want structuremap to get this for me (it implements IDoStuffWebServiceClientFactory).  It looks like IContext might help (http://docs.structuremap.net/UsingSessionContext.htm), but I'm struggling to figure out how this fits.

Any help greatly appreciated.
Roger.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To use the structuremap context in a Use method you can use the overload method that have a context as a parameter.

```
For<IDoStuffWebService>().Singleton().Use(ctx => ctx.GetInstance<IDoStuffWebServiceClientFactory>().Create());
```